# Implementing Key-value server

Tags: key-value

I found a question and that is : to implement a key-value server

1. User should be able to connect to server and be able to run command SET a = b.
2. On running command GET a, it should print b.

First of all, I didn't really understand what the question is all about.

Comment: Can I know what exactly is a Key-value server??

Answer (score 2):

In its simplest form, a Key-Value server is nothing more but a server that holds `keys` in a dictionary structure and associates a `value` with said key.

If it helps, you can think of a key as a variable name in a programming language or as an environment variable in the bash shell.

A client to the Key-Value server would either tell the server what value the key has, or request the current value of the key from the server.

As Ramon mentioned in his comment, [memcached.org](http://www.memcached.org) is such example of a Key-Value server.

Of course, the server can be much more complex that what I described above. Keys could be more than just values (for instance, objects) and the server/client could have a lot more functionality than the basic set/get.

Note that the term `Key-Value server` is very broad and doesn't mean anything concrete by itself. [NoSQL systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) make use of key-value stores, for example, so you could technically call any NoSQL database system a `Key-Value server`.